# "message":"Error: TypeError: (intermediate value) is not iterable"

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, mysql2

Currently I'm using mysql2 to connect to AWS Aurora DB.

I'm unable to connect or retrieve any records from the cluster.

```
connection = createConnection({
            host: 'music-instance-2.cairvpszramp.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
            user: 'user',
            password: 'password',
            database: 'music'
        });

    console.log("Before Connection")

    const [rows, fields] = await connection.execute('USE Music;SELECT * FROM artist;');
    console.log("After Connection")

    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(rows)
    };
```

The following error keeps popping up:

> Error Caught TypeError: (intermediate value) is not iterable at
> Runtime. (/var/task/index.js:27:36) at Generator.next
> () at fulfilled (/var/task/index.js:5:58)

What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

Notes:

- I'm using typescript
- This code is running inside an AWS lambda function with Nodejs18

`console.log(data)` output:

> _events: [Object: null prototype] {},_eventsCount: 0,
> _maxListeners: undefined, next: null, statement: undefined, sql: 'USE Music;SELECT * FROM artist;', values: undefined, onResult: undefined,
> parameters: undefined, insertId: 0,timeout: undefined, queryTimeout:
> null,
> _rows: [],
> _fields: [],
> _result: [],
> _fieldCount: 0,
> _rowParser: null,
> _executeOptions: { sql: 'USE Music;SELECT * FROM artist;', values: undefined },
> _resultIndex: 0,
> _localStream: null,
> _unpipeStream: [Function (anonymous)],
> _streamFactory: undefined,
> _connection: null, [Symbol(kCapture)]: false

Comment: It probably fails with `const [rows, fields]`, please change it to `const data = await ...` and show us what `data` is (just `console.log(data)`).

Comment: You are absolutely correct this was `const [rows, fields]` was the problem.

Comment: However I'm still unable to retrieve any records, you will find the data after being logged in the question after Notes

Answer (score 0):

The connection apparently returns `undefined` or `null` value. Those values are not *iterable*, you can't use *destructuring* on `undefined`. You could add a *fallback* value in case if the response is `undefined` or `null`.

```
const response = await connection.execute('USE Music;SELECT * FROM artist;');

const [rows, fields] = response || [];
                            // ^^^^^^^ secure possibility that response is undefined

return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(rows)
};
```